# Vintage Oscilloscope Preamp Whitepaper

Tags: oscilloscope, differential, preamp, cascode

Sometime early 90s I came across a whitepaper published by an oscilloscope manufacturer that described a custom preamp IC they had developed for their scopes. Does anyone know of this article?

The circuit was something like a differential doubly-cross coupled cascode; the article claimed it balanced settling time, accuracy and drift to do an order of magnitude better than the competition. I believe it was Tek but not their "measurement concepts" series. The article could have been quite old at the time (70s or 80s). The custom IC had a three-digit internal part#.

All these details could be incorrect, it was a long time back. But I still think about this circuit, it was just genius.

Comment: Used in various Tektronix analog scopes, e.g. 7904.

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps C.R. Battjes "AFTR Class Notes" Tektronix 1977. It describes a cascode "ft doubler" circuit. Referenced in **Wideband Amplifiers** (Starříč & Margan).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Was it ? if you use 2 differential amplifiers at half the gain of a single device  from the 2 devices summed together but twice the bandwidth of the single device to get twice the BW for a scope preamp.  A carefully chosen bias R produces the error voltage .

[image]
[image]